# How can I make a class that type-erases objects until a function is called on them without specifying the list of possible functions up front?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14, type-erasure

## Background

The title probably sounds confusing, so let me explain. First of all, here is a [minimal version of my implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23efb9aa3f59bb9e), so you can follow along with the concepts more easily. If you've seen some of Sean Parent's talks, you'll know he came up with a way to abstract polymorphism, allowing code such as this:

```
std::vector<Drawable> figures{Circle{}, Square{}};
for (auto &&figure : figures) {draw(figure);}
```

Notice that there are no pointers or anything. Calling `draw` on a `Drawable` will call the appropriate `draw` function on the contained object without the type of the object being easily accessible. One major downside to this is that similar classes to `Drawable` have to be written for each task. I'm trying to abstract this a bit so that the function does not have to be known by the class. My current solution is as follows:

```
std::vector<Applicator<Draw>> figures{Circle{}, Square{}};
for (auto &&figure : figures) {figure.apply(Draw{});}
```

Here, `Draw` is a functor with an `operator()(Circle)` and `opeator()(Square)`, or a generic version. In this way, this is also sort of a visitor pattern implementation. If you wanted to also, say, print the name of each figure, you could do `Applicator<Draw, PrintName>`. When calling `apply`, the desired function is chosen.

My implementation works by passing a `boost::variant` of the callable types to the virtual function and having it visit that variant and call the function within. Overall, I would say this implementation is acceptable, but I haven't yet thought much about allowing any number of parameters or a return type, let alone ones that differ from function to function.

## Question

I spent days trying to think of a way to have this work without making `Applicator` a template. Ideally, the use would be more similar to this. For the sake of simplicity, assume the functions called must have the signature `void(ObjectType)`.

```
//For added type strictness, I could make this Applicator<Figure> and have 
//using Figure<struct Circle> = Circle; etc
std::vector<Applicator> figures{Circle{}, Square{}}; 
for (auto &&figure : figures) {figure.apply(Draw{});} //or .apply(draw); if I can
```

The problem usually comes down to the fact that the type of the object can only be obtained within a function called on it. Internally, the class uses virtual functions, which means no templates. When `apply` is called, here's what happens (identical to Sean's talks):

1. The internal base class's apply is called on a pointer to the base class with the runtime type of a derived class.
2. The call is dispatched to the derived class, which knows the type of the stored object.

So by the time I have the object, the function to call must be reduced to a single type known within the class that both knows which function to call and takes the object. I cannot for the life of me come up with a way to do this.

## Attempts

Here are a couple of failed attempts so you can see why I find this difficult:

The premise for both of the first two is to have a type that holds a function call minus the unknown first argument (the stored object). This would need to at least be templated on the type of the callable object. By using Sean Parent's technique, it's easy enough to make a `FunctionCall<F>` class that can be stored in a `GenericFunctionCall`, much like a `Circle` in a `Figure`. This `GenericFunctionCall` can be passed into the virtual function, whereas the other cannot.

### Attempt 1

1. `apply()` is called with a known callable object type.
2. The type of the callable object is used to create a `FunctionCall<Type>` and store it as a type-erased `GenericFunctionCall`.
3. This `GenericFunctionCall` object is passed to the virtual `apply` function.
4. The derived class gets the call object and has the object to be used as the first argument available.
5. For the same reason of virtual functions not being allowed to be templates, the `GenericFunctionCall` could call the necessary function on the right `FunctionCall<Type>`, but not forward the first (stored object) argument.

### Attempt 2

As a continuation of attempt 1:

1. In order to pass the stored object into the function called on the `GenericFunctionCall`, the stored object could be type-erased into a `GenericObject`.
2. One of two things would be possible:

   - A function is called and given a proper `FunctionCall<Type>`, but has a `GenericObject` to give to it, with the type unknown outside of a function called on it. Recall that the function cannot be templated on the function call type.
   - A function is called and given a proper `T` representing the stored object, but has a `GenericFunctionCall` to extract the right function call type from. We're back where we started in the derived class's `apply` function.

### Attempt 3

1. Take the known type of a callable object when calling `apply` and use it to make something that stores a function that it can call with a known stored object type (like `std::function`).
2. Type-erase that into a `boost::any` and pass it to the virtual function.
3. Cast it back to the appropriate type when the stored object type is known in the derived class and then pass the object in.
4. Realize that this whole approach requires the stored object type to be known when calling `apply`.

---

Are there any bright ideas out there for how to turn this class into one that doesn't need the template arguments, but can rather take any callable object and call it with the stored object?

P.S. I'm open for suggestions on better names than `Applicator` and `apply`.

Comment: "without making it a template"-but it smells like a job for the CRTP (you can still use the CRTP and have only the helper class be templated)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, Sorry, I'm just not quite seeing what you're getting at. Could you elaborate?

Comment: By specifying the list of possible functions, you're actually defining the interface that the object should have, so it doesn't make sense to type-erase an object without defining the interface, or you should just use `boost::any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Consider a program composed of three translation units:

```
// tu1.cpp
void populate(std::vector<Applicator>& figures) {
  figures.push_back(Circle{});
  figures.push_back(Square{});
}

// tu2.cpp
void draw(std::vector<Applicator>& figures) {
  for (auto &&figure : figures) { figure.apply(Draw{}); }
}

// tu3.cpp
void combine() {
  std::vector<Applicator>& figures;
  populate(figures);
  draw(figures);
}
```

It must be possible for each TU to be translated separately, indeed in causal isolation. But this means that at no point is there a compiler that simultaneously has access to `Draw` and to `Circle`, so code for `Draw` to call `Circle::draw` can never be generated.

Comment: My intuition kept telling me there must be a way. You just beat it into submission. Thanks :)