# variable return type in function that returns held object of boost::any

Tags: c++, return-type, boost-any

Say I have a class `C` with a field of type `std::vector<boost::any>`. I have index operator `const boost::any C::operator[](const size_t i);` but what if I wanted `C::operator[](const size_t i)` to return the object held by the `any` object at index `i` rather than the `any`-object itself? The function would need a variable return type... which is not possible. Is there some way by for example means of indirection to achieve this anyway?

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible with `std::any` directly, even using the normal function call approach where the actual type is passed as an argument (think `std::variant` and `std::visit`). At a minimum, you'd need either a list of possible types up front (variant) or a list of possible operations up front (similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303718/how-can-i-make-a-class-that-type-erases-objects-until-a-function-is-called-on-th)).

Comment: A function needs to have a return type. A function template can have a return type that depends on template parameters.

Comment: Also, just step back a bit for a moment and catch a breath: How would a user *use* such a hypothetical function? Can you write down some example code from the caller's perspective?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, the user would use `C` to encode objects of any type to `size_t`s for more efficiency, after the `size_t`s have gone through an algorithm a sequence of other `size_t`s comes out and needs to be re-translated into the original objects, but there is no information about the objects in the IDs of type `size_t` and the number of types the objects can have is unlimited. Translation of objects to IDs and of IDs to objects happens via `C::operator[]`.

Comment: However, would there be a solution if the number of types the objects can have would be limited an known at compile time?

Comment: @KerrekSB, the template doesn't have to depend on any parameter. You can specify the template parameters explicitly, too. That's also what seems to be what the OP could do, although not with the index operator, I'm afraid. A simple `int n = my_store.get_at<int>(23);`. That's horribly unsave though, because nothing guarantees that the type at that index matches. Rather provide different stores for different object types. However, instead of storing an index, you could as well store a pointer then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Are you confusing parameters and arguments by chance? I am referring to the difference of `template <typename> int f()` vs `template <typename T> T f()`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I use the two terms "parameter" and "argument" synonymously. Anyhow, my first sentence should have read "the template parameter doesn't have to depend on any function parameter", that would have made it clearer. I fail to recall how exactly that was intended to relate to what you wrote above, I probably misread/misinterpreted what you wrote there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: And I use them correctly :-) The difference is usually not so important, except when it is, like here... In fact, I'd say that you'll probably have a lot harder time understanding "template argument deduction" if you confuse parameters and arguments.